# MPI_Gather submatrix to a matrix in master processor

Tags: c, matrix, mpi

I'd like to implement parallelized code which gathers each processor's submatrix to a matrix in master processor.

For example, what I want to implement is like this :

```
Input :
processor 0 : a a      processor 1 : b b
              a a                    b b
              a a                    b b
              a a                    b b
Output : 
processor 0 : a b a b
              a b a b 
              a b a b
              a b a b
```

Here's part of my code.

```
MPI_Datatype rowtype_temp, rowtype, coltype_temp, coltype, mtype_temp, mtype;
double **f, **f_local;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
local_n = n / comm_sz;

MPI_Type_vector(n, 1, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, &rowtype_temp);
MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype_temp);
MPI_Type_create_resized(rowtype_temp, 0, sizeof(double), &rowtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);

MPI_Type_vector(n, 1, n, MPI_DOUBLE, &coltype_temp);
MPI_Type_commit(&coltype_temp);
MPI_Type_create_resized(coltype_temp, 0, sizeof(double), &coltype);
MPI_Type_commit(&coltype);

MPI_Type_vector(local_n, 1, comm_sz, coltype, &mtype_temp);
MPI_Type_commit(&mtype_temp);
MPI_Type_create_resized(mtype_temp, 0, sizeof(double), &mtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&mtype);

f_local = (double**) malloc (n * sizeof(double *));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  f_local[i] = (double *) malloc (local_n * sizeof(double));
f = (double**) malloc (n  * sizeof(double *));
for (i = 0; i < n ; i++) f[i] = (double *) malloc (n * sizeof(double));


MPI_Gather(&f_local[0][0], local_n, rowtype, &f[0][0], 1 , mtype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and the output in this code looks like

```
processor 0 : a b a b
              0 0 0 0 
              0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0
```

Comment: For MPI, your matrix must be contiguous in memory. if you cannot use a 2D array (e.g. `double array[4][4];`) you need to allocate your matrix in one shot, and then build the jagged array. This kind of question is recurrent and was answered multiple times.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Hi, Thank you for your comment. It work! I never thought the allocation can be the problem. Thanks again.